# UI blocked by Task

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code that gets data from a site

```
    private void BeginCreationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Log("INFO", "Beggining ad creation");
        GeneralProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        foreach(var ad in ads)
        {
            string adUh = string.Empty;
            string errorMsg = string.Empty;
            bool error = false;

            //Task<string> uhFetch = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetUhForAdvert());
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HttpWebRequest newPromoRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.randomsite.com") as HttpWebRequest;
                newPromoRequest.CookieContainer = Cookies;
                newPromoRequest.Method = "GET";
                newPromoRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
                string uh = string.Empty;

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)newPromoRequest.GetResponse();

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet)))
                        {
                            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

                            doc.Load(sr);

                            adUh = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form")[0].SelectNodes("//input")[0].Attributes[2].Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            try
            {
                task.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                ae.Handle((x) =>
                {
                    errorMsg = x.Message + " | " + x.StackTrace;
                    error = true;

                    return error;
                });
            }

            if (error)
            {
                Log("ERROR", errorMsg);
            }

            Log("INFO", adUh);
        }
    }
```

However, while the task is executing, the UI is getting blocked but I'm not sure why it's happening. Not sure if it's the stream reading or HTML processing part as I'm using the Request code on other parts of my project without those two componentss and it works like a charm.

Comment: I'd guess `task.Wait();` is the cause of it. Try changing your click method to be async (`private async void`) and use `await task`.

Comment: @Alisson damn, such a tiny change did wonders. Please add your comment as an answer :D

Comment: @JhonAlx: [Here's why](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't block your UI thread using `task.Wait();`. Make your button click handler async like this:

```
private async void BeginCreationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // code here...
}
```

...and where you call:

```
task.Wait();
```

...call it like this:

```
await task;
```

---

Also, you shouldn't need to use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, you could simplify by just using `(HttpWebResponse)await newPromoRequest.GetResponseAsync();` and wrapping all the code of your task inside your `try catch` block.

---

> **EDIT:** You can read [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for a detailed explanation about this subject.